# How to use forEach for display and hide when mouseover and mouseout?

Tags: javascript, foreach

I create the HTML code. now i want to use forEach in JS when the mouse over, but when i use forEach method it just happen for first item not the others. i want its happen for each one when mouseover and mouseout.

my code link: `codepen.io/A_Mahdi28/pen/bGvOebr`

how do i use forEach method do it on all items?

Please help me.

Comment: forEach main product?

Comment: *"actually i have 5 time of these code"* - So the code you're asking about is different from what you're showing us?  *"Now i want to add these in JS when the mouse over"* - And the attempt you're showing us makes no attempt to use a `mouseover` event?  *"how do i use forEach method"* - By calling `.forEach()` on an array.  It's not really clear what you're trying to ask, or if the problem even has anything to do with `.forEach()` which seems to be the entire focus of the question.  Please provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates your attempt and indicate specifically what isn't working.

Comment: `id` attribute must be unique throughout the document, if the code you showed is one of the items, you won't be able use `getElementById()` to get element from other items. You are using `href` attribute in `<div>` which seems to be a mistake. `querySelector()` returns single element, you might need use `querySelectorAll` instead if you want to use `forEach`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With the given informations the following code may help you to understand the events you need for mouseover / mouseout.

In the HTML I have added "onmouseover / onmouseout" to your code pointing to  the functions show/hide. Inside those functions you can now execute your code for these events. If you are targeting a special div you have to also pass some parameters so you can identifiy the div you want to target.

```js
const mainProduct = document.querySelector('.main_product');
const mainInfo = document.getElementById('main_info');

mainProduct.classList.add('hidden');
mainInfo.style.filter = 'blur(2px)';

function show(target) {
  console.log(target);
  mainProduct.classList.remove('hidden');
  mainInfo.style.filter = 'blur(0)';
}

function hide(target) {
  console.log(target);
  mainProduct.classList.add('hidden');
  mainInfo.style.filter = 'blur(2px)';
}
```

```html
<div href="#" class="review_book" onmouseover="show(event.target)" onmouseout="hide(event.target)">
      <div id="main_info">
        <img src="/img/Reviews/1984.jpg" alt="1984 Cover" />
        <div class="main_description">
          <p class="book_name">1984</p>
          <p class="book_author">George Orwell</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main_product hidden">
        <div href="#">
          <button class="btn see_review--btn">
            <i class="ph-eye"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
        <button class="btn add_wishlist--btn">
          <i class="ph-bookmark-simple"></i>
        </button>
        <button class="btn add_cart--btn">
          <i class="ph-shopping-cart"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

So if you want to target a specific div you can either add an index to the classlist or pass the event directly in the mouseover. If you now check those events you should be able to extract the main_product and main_info of that event and manipulate the css of those.

Comment: Please explain your solution. What have you done to tackle the issue?

Comment: From my experience guesses and "not sure" answers are voted down, regardless of if they are right or wrong...just FYI...

Comment: sad story :D. ty